# javascript, загрузка текста страницы

Tags: javascript

Как можно через js загрузить весь код страницы, и сохранить в переменную, как строку например "http://yandex.ru"?

Comment: Только через JS - никак.

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @tutankhamun AJAX  запрос на чужой домен. С каких пор это стало просто и без проблем?

Comment: Без ajax почитайте var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()  там можно делать GET запросы.

Comment: Получается, что через ajax можно делать запросы только на сайт, откуда эта страница была загружена?

Comment: @newman Ну да. Логично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том виде, в котором задан вопрос это невозможно.

Системы безопастности браузеров позволяют делать AJAX запросы только к тому домену, с которого была загружена страница с данным javascript.

В общем виде возможны crossdomain запросы - когда данные запрашиваются с другого домена. Но в этом случае на этом домене должны быть сделаны настройки, позволяющие делать такие запросы.

Если говорить о вопросе, то вряд ли yandex.ru разрешает такие кроссдоменые запросы с любых сайтов.

Более подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#cors)

Comment: А почему если я ставлю в url метода getJSON, например, ссылку на другой сайт с api, и ввожу ее так, как в документации, то все получается? Это ведь тоже получение данных с другого домена

Comment: @Юрий потому что на том домене разрешили кроссдоменные запросы. Весь вопрос в том разрешены они на том сайте с которого вы хотите загружать данные или нет.

Comment: а я могу на своем домене разрешить их?